# JQuery css() and JavaScript style

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm confusing.

I have a button

```
<button onclick="foo(this)" id="bar">Button</button>
```

And I code JavaScript like this:

```
var foo = function(param)
{
    param.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
};
```

It worked... When I clicked the backgroundColor changed to blue!!

But when I use JQuery css() method, like:

```
var foo = function(param)
{
    param.css('background-color', 'blue');
};
```

Nothing happened !

Of course I did add the JQuery library !! But nothing happend and I don't know why..?

Comment: Wrap the `param` inside `jQuery`. Eg:- `jQuery(param).css('background-color', 'blue');`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Nothing happened !

That's unlikely. What should have happened was that the Console in your browser's developer tools should have said something along the lines of:

> ```
> Uncaught TypeError: param.css is not a function(…)
> ```

Always look at your browser's developer tools when debugging JavaScript.

---

jQuery doesn't add new methods to HTML Element objects.

`css` is a method of jQuery objects. You need to call it on a jQuery object.

```
jQuery(param).css(etc etc)
```

Answer (score 2):

`param` refers to the dom object in  `foo()`, `css()` method is defined on `$` object in jquery so use `$(param)`

Answer (score 2):

Since `.css` is a jQuery function. So, you should wrap the `param` inside `jQuery`. Like:-

```
jQuery(param).css('background-color', 'blue');
```

`.css` will always work with an element selected with jQuery. See Example in [Docs](http://api.jquery.com/css/)